# Can't log into Workbench with roles developer, manager, or user

Tags: drools, kie-workbench

I have Workbench 6.2 on Tomcat running.

I can log in with admin or analyst role, but can't login users with a role of developer, manager or user.

```
  <role rolename="analyst"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="developer"/>
  <role rolename="kie-server"/>
  <role rolename="user"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>

  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,user,manager-gui,admin"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="albert" password="albert" roles="manager-gui,admin,user"/>
  <user username="analyst" password="analyst" roles="analyst"/>
  <user username="developer" password="developer" roles="developer"/>
  <user username="kie-server" password="kie-server" roles="kie-server"/>
  <user username="user" password="user" roles="user"/>
  <user username="manager" password="manager" roles="manager"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly the behaviour the readme in TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/kie-drools-wb/README.txt describes.

> 2e. Edit TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml to include roles and users, make sure there will be 'analyst' or 'admin' roles defined as it's required to be authorized to use kie-wb